# Change color of Icon in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the color of my thumbs up button in Material UI. I'd like to change it to white, but right now it's blue. This is my code:

```
        <div className={styles.like_dislike}>
            <IconButton
                size="medium"
                sx={{ ml: 2 }}
            >
                {likeStatus === 1
                    ? <ThumbUpIcon onClick={handleLike} color='primary'/>
                    : <ThumbUpOffAltIcon onClick={handleLike} color="primary" />
                }
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
                size="medium"
                sx={{ ml: 2 }}
            >
            {likeStatus === -1
                ? <ThumbDownIcon onClick={handleDislike} />
                : <ThumbDownOffAltIcon onClick={handleDislike} />
            }
            </IconButton>
        </div>
```

I have a section in my CSS file modifying `MuiIcon-colorPrimary`, as that is what [MUI specifies](https://mui.com/api/icon/) to modify for icons using the primary color:

```
.like_dislike.MuiIcon-colorPrimary {
    color: #fafafa
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try `color:#fafafa !important;`

Comment: Can you create a reproducible [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or similar? It would help us to help.